# Design a Javascript object to output to console.log as a string as per new Date()

Tags: javascript

How is it that `console.log(new Date());` shows a string at the console?

How do I imitate that behaviour in my objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method in your object's prototype:

```
var Demo = function(){};
Demo.prototype.toString = function(){ return "Demo string"; };

var test = new Demo();
console.log(test); // results in "Demo string"
```

Note that this could slightly alter the behaviour of your code, since the non-type safe comparison operator `==` will use this function in some circumstances if the left and right hand side are not of the same type:

```
if(test == "Demo String"){
    console.log("Equal!");
}
if(test !== "Demo String"){
    console.log("But not same type!");
}
```

However, it seems that `console.log` [hasn't been standardized yet](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-script-coord/2012OctDec/0377.html), so there is no uniform solution. Note that you can still use `console.log(test + "")` to trigger the call of `toString`.

Comment: This doesn't work in either firebug or chrome console. The output shows the Demo object, not a string representation.

Comment: @dsjbirch: Please add the exact code you tried to your question, as the steps I described work without problems in FF17.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a jsfiddle and opened the console. I'm using firefox 15.0 and chrome ?

Comment: @dsjbirch: The built-in console doesn't show this behaviour. However, it seems that `console.log` [hasn't been standardized yet](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-script-coord/2012OctDec/0377.html), so there is no uniform solution. Note that you can still use `console.log(test + "")` to trigger the call of `toString`.

Comment: The joys of JavScript! Thanks for the great answer. Accepted. Could you just add words to the effect of your comment re: non-standardization into your answer, so anyone that comes here after doesn't miss the info in your comment responses.