# Display object like Date or String

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, date, firefox

In the console on Chrome and Firefox you can make an object look like an array by adding `[].splice` and `length` to the prototype

Demo:

```
var test = function(){}; 
test.prototype.splice = [].splice; 
test.prototype.length = 0;  
new test;
```

Is there any way to display something like a  `Date` or `String`

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert an object to an array?

Comment: Date is displayed as a normal string in console if I'm not mistaken, what special handling are you after?

Comment: @Mathew Maybe you're right, but how do you display it like a string when it's in fact an instance of a constructor?

Comment: @Connor Instead of `console.log`, try `console.dir` like `console.dir(Date)` or `console.dir(Date())` - Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Connor Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114431/design-a-javascript-object-to-output-to-console-log-as-a-string-as-per-new-date) help?

Comment: @Mathew I've tried it and it doesn't work, the answer is incorrect :/

Comment: To everyone, The Array was an example of faking the display of an object I want to display something like a Date / String

Comment: @Connor as the comments in that answer, There seems to be no standard way for that.

Comment: What if you implement valueOf and return a Date or string there?

Comment: @HMR I have done that, but it only triggers the valueOf method when you convert it to a string, like `"" + date`